# netCDF files in R

Tags: r, gis, netcdf, cdo-climate

I have netCDF file obtained from [here](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded/data.gpcc.html) with name **precip.mon.total.v6.nc**. I am using `ncdf` package in R to open and analyse the file.

```
 new <- open.ncdf("precip.mon.total.v6.nc")
    > new
    [1] "file precip.mon.total.v6.nc has 4 dimensions:"
    [1] "lat   Size: 360"
    [1] "lon   Size: 720"
    [1] "nbnds   Size: 2"
    [1] "time   Size: 1320"
    [1] "------------------------"
    [1] "file precip.mon.total.v6.nc has 1 variables:"
    [1] "float precip[lon,lat,time]  Longname:GPCC Monthly total of     precipitation Missval:-9.96920996838687e+36"
```

But when I extract the variable, I got the error

```
      > get.var.ncdf(new, "precip")
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.5 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In double(totvarsize) :
  Reached total allocation of 2047Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In double(totvarsize) :
  Reached total allocation of 2047Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In double(totvarsize) :
  Reached total allocation of 2047Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In double(totvarsize) :
  Reached total allocation of 2047Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

My queries are:
         (a) How to handle memory issue?
         (b) How can I change the resolution of this netCDF file from 0.5*0.5 to 0.25*0.25 data? I have tried the similar problem in MATLAB. It can tackle memory issue better than R for netCDF files. But changing resolution is still a problem as I am not good at MATLAB. I will be very thankful for any help in this direction.

Comment: You part b is a very large and open ended question. You need to look at downscaling, a common option is using a lapse rate - for this you'll need an elevation grid of the resolution you wish to downscale to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you extract your variable, you need to specify which dimensions you want. Currently you're asking R to get everything and so I suspect it's creating a 3D array which will likely be enormous.

The ncdf4 package generally supersedes ncdf, you should try using that instead. You need to decide if you want to read data by location for time or by time step for location. This is easier to envisage on a plain 2D grid:

- Single cell at all time steps
- All locations single time step

Yours is a 3D grid through time (albeit with the 3rd dimension only two bands), however it looks like your variable isn't using the bands dimension. Here's a 2D workflow based on ncdf4, ignoring your bands:

Package:

```
install.packages("ncdf4")
library(ncdf4)
```

Open connection:

```
nc = nc_open("~/dir/dir/file.nc")
```

**For a grid at one time step**

Read dimensions:

```
precip = list()
precip$x = ncvar_get(nc, "lon")
precip$y = ncvar_get(nc, "lat")
```

Read data (note start is the index in dimensions to begin and count is how many observations from that point, so here we read the whole grid at the first time step):

```
precip$z = ncvar_get(nc, "precip", start=c(1, 1, 1), count=c(-1, -1, 1))
# Convert to a raster if required
precip.r = raster(precip)
```

**To read a single cell at all time steps**

You need to find your cell index, `precip$x` and `precip$y` will help. Once you have it (e.g. cell x=5 and y=10):

```
precip.cell = ncvar_get(nc, "precip", start=c(5, 10, 1), count=c(1, 1, -1))
```

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I am using windows for which `ncdf4` is not available. But I will surely look in to linux. How can I go through the changing resolution problem? (Specially in case of comparison of rainfall data with different resolutions, for example 2.13*1.8 and 1*1). Please suggest some readings or web links.

Comment: Here's an answer I did on aligning grids in R: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157557/clip-raster-by-raster-with-data-extraction-and-resolution-change/157597#157597 perhaps this paper will be of use for your downscaling: http://www.iac.ethz.ch/doc/publications/2007_Schmidli_StatDyn.pdf as I said, downscaling is a big topic.

Comment: I put a guide together to get your Linux box ready for NetCDF4: https://scottishsnow.wordpress.com/2015/06/08/getting-ready-for-netcdf-4/ it might be of use!

Answer (score 1):

(a) memory:

If on a linux box [sudo apt-get install cdo] (or also windows with cygwin installed) you can use cdo to help you out.

For example, if you are only interested in a specific date you can select that first to keep the file size down:

```
cdo seldate,date in.nc out.nc
```

or you might have wanted to view the time mean:

```
cdo timmean in.nc out.nc
```

That will keep the file size down, and you can then open it in R to make your plot (or use ncview for a quickview investigation).

(b) remapping

cdo can also interpolate the file to 0.25 degrees, (although I am not sure why you would want to do this, as you are not adding any information and you are making the files four times larger!!!)

```
cdo remapcon,r1440x720 in.nc out.nc
```

or

```
cdo remapnn,r1440x720 in.nc out.nc
```

But as I said, if you want to interpolate to compare to another 0.25 degree product (e.g. TRMM), better to go the other way and interpolate the finer dataset to 0.5 degree.

By the way, in 2015, v7 was released of GPCC, still at 0.5 degree.