# R - Creating a raster - Right dimensions?

Tags: r, matrix, coordinates, raster

I have a list like the one below. Its extracted from a nc-file. I used this [netCDF files in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32183495/netcdf-files-in-r) as an example.

```
ex = list()
ex$x = matrix((seq(-40,40, length = 89 * 86)), 89,86)
ex$y = matrix((seq(30,80, length = 89 * 86)), 89,86)
ex$z = matrix((runif(89 * 86, 20, 120)))
```

Now I am at the point, where my list looks like the one below and I want to create a raster out of it.

```
library(raster)
exR = raster(ex)
```

But I get an error message: `Error in .local(x, ...) : "z" does not have the right dimensions`

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Your x and y coordinates should be a 1 dimension vector, while z is a matrix with that x and y dimensions.

```
ex = list()
ex$x = seq(-40,40, length = 89)
ex$y = seq(30,80, length = 86)
ex$z = matrix(runif(89 * 86, 20, 120),89,86)              

library(raster)
exR = raster(ex)
```

[image]

Comment: But my problem is that I cant change that. Its given like that when I extract it from the file. It already is a matrix when I get it.

Comment: I cannot download the .nc your are using, you should be able to open it with the `ncdf4` package and read its dimensions as a vector: `nc$dim$lat$vals` and `nc$dim$lon$vals`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I cant give you the original file. When I type in nc$dim$x$vals I get numbers from 1-89, and for nc2$dim$y$vals I get numbers from 1-86. But those are not the actual gridboxes, arent they?